# JavaScript Output of it "1" - - "1" is 2 how?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript :  `"1" - - "1"` give us `2` in output whereas if I'll write like `"1"--"1"` getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

The one that works i.e. `"1" - - "1"`

```js
console.log("1" - - "1")
```

The one that doesn't works i.e. `"1"--"1"`

```js
console.log("1"--"1");
```

It is totally weird for me.

Comment: Really unclear... Could you please create a snippet to reproduce this ?

Answer (score 10):

The `-` operator casts the string `"1"` to a number.

So, `"1" - - "1"` is equivalent to:

```
1 - (-1)
```

So: 2!

Whereas, `"1"--"1"` would fail because operator `--` expects only one operand.  `"1"--"1"` just doesn't make sense. In the first case you had an additional space between the `-` minuses - which made them two different operators.

Answer (score 7):

When the two `-` symbols are joined together, they form the [unary `--` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement). That operator needs a variable to act on, and since `"1"` is not a variable, you get an error.

When the two `-` are apart, then the first of the two is the [subtraction operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Subtraction_(-)), and the second is the [unary negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary). This is valid syntax and yields 2.

Answer (score 2):

`--` and `- -` are not the same.

`--` is the [Postfix Decrement Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-postfix-decrement-operator). `foo--` means "Take the value of the variable `foo`, subtract 1 from it, assign it back to `foo`. A string literal is not a variable so this causes an error when you try `"a string"--`.

`-` can either be the [Unary - Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-minus-operator) or the [Subtraction Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus) depending on context.

In the case of `"1" - - "1"`, you have one of each.

The second `-` is a Unary - Operator and converts the `"1"` to its right to `-1`. The other is the subtraction operator.

If you subtract "negative one" from "one" you get "two".

Answer (score 0):

Its simple algebra and Javascript type logic here...

So the algebra part:

The statement evaluates to `1-(-1)` which is `2`.

Its like you have 1 dollar and you subtract 1 doller you own to a friend. Which gives you 2 dollars because you don't have to give him the dollar back (this is technically, you don't really get another dollar).

The Javascript part:

This works because Javascript can calculate string *if* they are numbers. So Javascript can convert `"1"` to `1`.